# run time of described solution to finding median of 2 sorted array

Tags: algorithm

list 1 [1,3]

list 2 [2]

the median between l1 and l2 ([1,2,3]) = 2

my solution is to basically merge the arrays as you would in merge sort...

two pointers i and j and insert based on which is less or if one has reached the end just insert the other... stop inserting at middle and return either the most recently visited value or most (recent + next) / 2 if the combined list lengths ard even

can anyone explain the runtime to this? and a brief description of a possible O(log(m+n)) run time algo

edit: would a possible O(log(m+n)) include inserting all elements of the second list into the first with a binary search insert and then return the avg from the created list?

edit2: you would insert all of the items from the smaller list into the larger list with binary search insert so it would be O(log(min(m,n))

edit3: though i'm not entirely sure how I would implement inserting items from one list into another

thanks so much for helping me... trying to study for interviews

Comment: what does it mean finding the median of 2 sorted array?

Comment: two sorted arrays of ints.. if they were combined as one sorted array what would be the median?

Comment: added a basic example

Comment: Please explain further are you asking for the middle value of both arrays inside the array or if you add all the elements of the arrays together finding the number in the arrays closest to the median(all elements added / number of elements)

Comment: To understand a possible O(log(n+m)) solition, consider this. Suppose you find a median of array 1. Now binary search that value in array 2. (It doesn't have to be there, but you will find a place where it *would* be). Suppose it is exactly in the middle of array 2. Can you immediately find the median of the unified array? What if it falls in the left half of array 2, hoe do you proceed?

Comment: Consider that you must loop through the elements in both array to copy it into another new array